# User name is not updated after re-login with different user

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I created a simple flutter android app and I wanted to display 'User name' on the home screen which is navigated after the 'Login' or 'Sign Up' process. I achieved this using 'GetX' and now it displays 'User Name' on the home screen correctly. However, when I sign out and re-login using a different Username/Password it still displays the previous login user's Username. Further, I noticed that after closing the app and re-open it updates with the correct username. Can anybody tell what is the cause of the issue?

Controller :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/constants/route_names.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/locator.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/models/user.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/services/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/services/navigation_service.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/viewmodels/base_model.dart';

class HomeViewModel extends GetxController implements BaseModel {
  final CollectionReference _usersCollectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  final AuthenticationService _authenticationService =
      locator<AuthenticationService>();
  final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late RxList<YUser> users = RxList<YUser>([]);
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    users.bindStream(findByUserID(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid));
    print(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid);  // **(I noticed that this line prints at the initial login only and not priting subsequent logins)**
    update();
  }
  Stream<List<YUser>> findByUserID(String uid) {
    final userRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').withConverter<YUser>(
              fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => YUser.fromData(snapshot.data()!),
              toFirestore: (user, _) => user.toJson(),
            );
    return userRef
        .where('id', isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) => query.docs.map((item) => YUser.fromMap(item)).toList());
  }
```

View:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/viewmodels/home_view_model.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeViewModel>{
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 final controller = Get.put(HomeViewModel());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<HomeViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => HomeViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Obx(() => Text((controller.users.length>0) ? controller.users[0].fullName : '')),
                 
                ),
                
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: model.signOut,
                  child: Text('Sign Out'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Pubspec.yaml :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.7
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  get: ^4.3.8
  provider: ^5.0.0
  stacked: ^2.2.3
  stacked_services: ^0.8.13
```

Comment: Print the values where: you get the name, you save the name, you set the Text() with the name, when you log out, when you log in again... Then you can see what happens and why it does not change. Maybe the problem is here, you always use the first person in the list... `Text((controller.users.length>0) ? controller.users[0].fullName : '')),`

Comment: onInit is run only once, firebase auth has listen for user changes stream, listen to that for user update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to listen for firebase user changes

```
onInit(){
 FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user){
 //user is the new user, update your view accordingly
 //here you can use
 firebaseAuth.currentUser;
 //or
 user; //the user variable
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but now it creates a new issue 'Null check operator used on a null value' at users.bindStream(findByUserID(user!.uid));

I used as follows,

  void onInit() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
      users.bindStream(findByUserID(user!.uid));
    });
  }

Comment: Only use "!" Operator if you are sure it's non null, check for null rather than using !, Debug in case of null